# Remote-Containers Extension of VS Code not able to execute docker commands

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

### Setup:

- Ubuntu 20.04 distro running inside WSL2 (5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2)
- VS Code version 1.55.2 installed in Windows
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0 installed in WSL2
- docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305 installed in WSL2
- Remote-Containers Extension for VS Code v0.166.1 installed locally (I could not find an option to explicitly install this inside WSL2, but I am not sure if this even matters, see below)

### Original error:

When I open the command palette and enter `Remote-Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container`, I get the error `The 'docker' command was not found. Make sure Docker is installed' in a pop up window.

### What I tried:

#### Attempt 1

First, I thought that the Remote-Containers extension wants to execute the docker commands inside windows and not WSL2. Since I don't have Docker Desktop installed on Windows, it is impossible to execute docker commands in Windows. So I tried downloading a specific version of the the Remote-Containers extension file from the marketplace [v0.165.0 I believe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode-remote/vsextensions/remote-containers/0.165.0/vspackage), copying it into the VS extension folder inside WSL2 `/home/kevinsuedmersen/.vscode-server/extensions` and installing it manually from the VS Code Extension panel. However, this also installed the Remote-Containers extension *locally*, so probably on Windows. I am not sure if *locally* means that this extension is available globally, but nevertheless, I am still getting the error that the docker command is not found as explained above.

#### Attempt 2

I notice that when I open a PowerShell on Windows, I can use the docker daemon inside WSL2 by prepending `wsl` to all docker commands, e.g. `wsl docker run hello-world`. So, I went to the VS Code and in settings (Settings > Remote > Containers > Docker Path), I changed the docker path from `docker` to `wsl docker`, but then, I got this error `Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend required`. This is even the case on another laptop, where I actually have Docker Desktop installed and the WSL2 backend enabled.

#### Attempt 3

I tried changing the docker path in VS code to the full path of the docker socket in WSL2 `/var/run/docker.sock`, but then I got the error `Current user does not have permission to run 'docker'. Try adding the user to the 'docker' group`. My current user `kevinsuedmersen` is already member of the docker group.

Any advice or directions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given on the GitHub Repo of the VS-Remote-Container Extension here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4914

Comment: Details should be placed in the answer.